# How to convert Slick result in desired format?

Tags: scala, akka, h2, akka-http, slick-3.0

I have domain object of type `Person` which is defined in case class as follows:

```
case class Person(personName: String, personAge: Int, personId: Long = 0)
```

and corresponding query table is as follows:

```
final case class PersonTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Person](tag, "people") {

  def personId = column[Long]("person_id", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)

  def personName = column[String]("person_name")

  def age = column[Int]("person_age")

  def * = (personName, age, personId).mapTo[Person]
}
```

and I have domain object of type `Address` which is dfined in case class as follows:

```
case class Address(houseNumber: Int, street: String
, state: String, ownerId: Long, id: Long = 0)
```

Its corresponding table class is defined as below. Person and address have one to many relation (***one person can have many addresses but one address belongs to only one person***)

```
final case class AddressTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Address](tag, "addresses") {
  def houseNumber = column[Int]("house_number")

  def street = column[String]("street_name")

  def state = column[String]("state_name")

  def addressId = column[Long]("address_id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

  def ownerId = column[Long]("owner_id")

  def owner = foreignKey("owner_fk", ownerId, TableQuery[PersonTable])(_.personId, onDelete = ForeignKeyAction.Cascade)

  def * = (houseNumber, street, state, ownerId, addressId).mapTo[Address]
}
```

I want to return following type of JSON result from my `Akka-http` based REST API (**addresses should be returned as an array**):

```
{
    "name": "shekhar",
    "age": 30,
    "id": 1234,
    "addresses": [{
            "house_number": 1,
            "street": "water street",
            "state": "foo bar",
            "owner_id": 1234,
            "address_id": 9874
        },
        {
            "house_number": 99,
            "street": "foo bar street",
            "state": "foo disk state",
            "owner_id": 1234,
            "address_id": 007
        }
    ]
}
```

To get this result I wrote query using Slick as shown below:

```
  val peopleQueries = TableQuery[PersonTable]
  val addressQueries = TableQuery[AddressTable]
  val query = peopleQueries.filter(_.personName === "Shekhar") joinLeft addressQueries on (_.personId === _.ownerId)
  val futureResultData = db.run(query.result)
```

I get result for this in following structure (**person details are repeated for each address**):

```
Vector(
  (Person("shekhar",30,1234),
    Some(Address(1,"Water Street","foo bar",1234,9874))
  )
  , (Person("shekhar",30,1234),
    Some(Address(99,"foo bar street","foo disk state",1234,007))
  )
)
```

To convert the above to expected JSON format, I can wait until DB query has run and write some Scala code to bring it desired format but that will block the request until this post-processing is complete (please correct me if I am wrong about it).

my code will look like below:

```
futureResultData.onComplete {
  case Success(data) => // code to bring data in desired format
}
```

I would like to know if there is any way to get the **result in asynchrounous/non-blocking way**?

---

Thanks to [Pedro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11290903/pedro-correia-lu%C3%ADs), I was able to find solution to this problem.

Solution which worked for me is as below:

```
futureResultData.map( x => {
        x.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2.get))
})
```

Comment: You can map the Future and work with that

Comment: @PedroCorreiaLuís can you please give some pointer/hints about how to do it? I read this article about "mapping the Future" but I am not able to understand it clearly https://blog.knoldus.com/map-flatmap-on-futures-options-in-scala/

Comment: You can think of the future as an odd kind of collection, which contains just one element. All else is done by the magic of the `Future` class. So `map`, `flatMap` work just like they do on `Seq`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
futureResultData.map {
  _.transformInDesiredFormat // code to bring data in desired format
}
```

If you post the actual code that transforms i can help you more

Futures are monads, so when you map, you work with what is in that future, If you have a Future[Int] and you map that Future, inside the map you work with the Int.

Example:

```
val aFuture = Future.successful(1)
aFuture.map(f=>  f+ 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It has helped me understanding things better. I wrote following code to get the desired result but I am not sure if it will block the thread or it will get executed in Future

futureResultData.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2.get))

Comment: What will be the best way to share actual code with you? GitHub?

Comment: @Shekhar yeah GitHub